# Why wont the websocket server stay alive after start

Tags: java, websocket, process, webserver, java-websocket

i am using `org.java-websocket` for my websocket server, i have the normal "Main" Class which extends `WebSocketServer` and has all its methods. i also have this constructor.

```
public WebServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
        super(address);
}
```

which is used in the main method....

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 4444;
        System.out.println("Started WebServer");
        WebSocketServer server = new WebServer(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        server.setConnectionLostTimeout(0);
        server.run();
    }
```

it says the "Started WebServer" but then just "Process finished with exist code 0"

Comment: As of testing, "0" means that the application is already running!.